# On Scrolling Nav Go Behind Slider

Tags: html, css

When I scroll down my menubar go behind the cycle slider it works fine on other section only troubling on slide.I tried `z-index 1` but its not working.please give any solution.I don't know whats going wrong.
Live demo http://40.86.75.38/download/slide/

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section_about{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<Script type ="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="slider-main">
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <div class="cycle-pager">

    </div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="section_about">

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style header element with `postion:fixed` and `z-index`

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:777;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* Top Menu Start Here */

header {
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.container{
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section_about{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<Script type ="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container"></div>
  
  <div id="slider-main">
  <div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <div class="cycle-pager">

    </div>
  <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section_about">

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```